# Jenkins plugin to display file during test build

Tags: selenium, jenkins-plugins

I have a very specific situation. I have created runtime reports in my framework which will create HTML result file at the end of the very first test case and it will keep appending the test results till the last test ends. So results will be available at the end of first test run itself and we can see and analyze the results. But in jenkins report publishers are post build actions and now I need something to display the file early during the test build. I could not find any plugin. Is there a way we can achieve that?

Comment: Is this question related to selenium?

Comment: Not actually, but in my case I am using Selenium ReportNg listeners to generate report. But runtime report is again a customized form, where locally report starts generating early and keep appending results in html. but unable to figure out that how to achieve the same using jenkins.